# How fast do binary stars orbit each other?

Tags: gravity, orbital-mechanics, stars

Specifically I am wondering how fast a Class G star and a white dwarf would orbit each other in a type P binary system. How far away would they have to be from each other to have a stable orbit and how fast would they orbit each other?

Comment: What is your worldbuilding problem? I read a plain Astronomy question here.

Comment: In short, the stars can orbit at pretty much any speed, depending on how close they are (and their masses). If they’re nearly touching, they’ll be moving very quickly, whereas if they’re very far apart, they’ll orbit once every thousand years or more. If you have a set distance in mind, I’d recommend just googling “orbital period.” You can easily find the equations you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Even ignoring that this is more of a calculation question than a worldbuilding problem, without further information, it is basically impossible to calculate this.**

One thing to keep in mind is that two masses can orbit each other at any speed, and then you'd calculate distance, or , any distance and then you'd calculate speed.
So depending on what you have in mind, your stars could be very close and orbit very quickly, or very far away and orbit very slowly.

To calculate this, I'd assume that the mass of the class G star is 1 solar mass, and that the white dwarf's mass is 4 solar masses.
Speed of orbit necessary² = μ * (2 / r - 1 / a)

where Speed of orbit necessary is the relative satellite speed (compared to the speed of a star),

μ is the standard gravitational parameter μ = G * (M + m),

r is the distance between the star and the satellite,

a is the semi-major axis of the elliptical orbit,

G is the gravitational constant G = 6.674 * 10 ^(-11) N * m² / kg²,

M is the mass of the star,

m is the mass of the satellite.

Notice that I need more information to actually calculate the equation. All I can give you is that the standard gravitational parameter is 663737256000 km/s.

If you can give me the distance at both apoapsis and periapsis, I can give you the velocity that they would have at their respective points.

Alternatively, you may provide the Semi-major and Semi-Minor axes of the Class G, and I can calculate the velocity/distance for apoapsis/periapsis from there. You could also give me both the velocity of the Class G and its distance at either apoapsis or periapsis.